# sans-serif font for ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I'm a beginner in R.

I want to make a figure that includes a text, but it should meet the condition as below:

"All text should be sans-serif typeface, preferably Helvetical or Arial."

So I searched ways to change my font type,

but I'm not sure this code satisfies the condition.

Is base_family='sans' means sans-serif font?

Thanks a lot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(extrafont)
theme_set(theme_grey(base_family='sans'))

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, color=Species)) +
  geom_point()+
  labs(title="Is this font sans-serif?")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a serif-free font. Sans and sans-serif are synonyms.
The default 'sans' font in ggplot is Helvetica.

Comment: It is actually platform dependent which font are the default 'sans', 'mono' and 'serif' fonts. For example, on Windows, the default 'sans' font is Arial.